# User "John Rock" violates the SE content policy

Tags: support, spam

This user profile:

https://english.stackexchange.com/users/21563/john-rock

and the 32 other SE profiles linked to it were evidently created to provide link juice for traffic generation through the bio page to a merchandise site, not to publish meaningful content. The user has no reputation, apparently because it has never posted, voted, or contributed in any way in the fifteen months since its creation.

This violates the [SE content policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy).

> **Spam**. Users that do not publish meaningful content, use deceptive means to generate revenue or traffic, or whose primary purpose is affiliate marketing, will be suspended.

Comment: The account has had seven visitors in total in the space of 15 months. Can you call him a spammer? He's never posted a question or an answer, hard to see how he can generate any traffic to his website.

Comment: @Mari-LouA it may give the target websites "Google juice", even when there's [nofollow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow).

Comment: @Mari-LouA Andrew gets it.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I read the link and did not understand much. No. I lie. nothing apart from Google devising a method so embedded links won't be counted in their equation... something like that. Maybe because I'm feeling tired, I'll have a butcher's tomorrow. Still, how you can direct traffic if no one clicks on your link seems nonsensical, but if you say so, I believe you! :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Pages appear sooner in Google search results if they are linked to by other pages. The links in the profile are intended to manipulate Google search results into directing more traffic to the merchandise site.